# How Can I acquire Mules Logger Instance In Spring Bean?

Tags: java, log4j, mule

I understand that there is a built in log4j instance and configuration inside Mule ESB, is there any way to acquire that exact instance from within the associated Spring Bean so that i can log into the same file that mule use (the file inside Mule-standalone\logs) ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the log4j or slf4j api inside your spring bean and, since it is loaded in the mule context, the same logging settings will be used.